# Print parallelogram using function C++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

I try to print a diamond with nRows.
The first program worked but then when I break it to functions following these instruction:
GetNRows( void );
DrawShape( int nRows );
numberSpaces( int nRows, int row );
numberStars( int nRows, int row );
PrintChars( int n, char ch );
I don't know how to pass by value into a function and update the value every time pass in.
Please take a look at my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getNRows(int &);
int calcNumSpace( int nRows, int row );
int calcNumStars( int nRows, int row );
void printChars( int n, char ch );
void drawShape( int nRows );

int main()
{
    int nRows;
    getNRows( nRows );
    drawShape( nRows );
    return 0;
}
int getNRows(int &nRows)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter number of rows (3-23) :";
        cin >> nRows;
    }while ( nRows > 23 || nRows < 3);
    if ( nRows % 2 == 0)
    {
        nRows += 1;
    }
    return nRows;
}
void drawShape( int nRows )
{
    int n, row;
    for( row = 0; row < nRows; row++ )
    {
        n = calcNumSpace( nRows, row );
        printChars( n, ' ' );
        n = calcNumStars(nRows, row );
        printChars( n, '*' );
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int calcNumSpace( int nRows, int row )
{
    int space;
    !!! What shoud I do here to update space every time row increase 1 ???
    return space;
}
int calcNumStars( int nRows, int row )
{
    int stars;
    same for space above!!!
    return stars;
}
void printChars( int n, char ch )
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Enter number of rows (3-23) :5
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Here my first program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i=0 , j=0, k=0, space, stars;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter number of rows (3-23) :";
        cin >> n;
    }while ( n > 23 || n < 3);
    if ( n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n += 1;
    }
// print top half
    space = n / 2;
    stars = 1;
    for( i = 0; i < n / 2 + 1; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < space; j++ )
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for( k = 0; k < stars; k++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
        stars = stars + 2;
        space = space - 1;
    }
// print bottom half
    space = 1;
    stars = n - 2;
    for( i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < space; j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for( k = 0; k < stars; k++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
        space = space + 1;
        stars = stars - 2;
    }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said 'The first program worked'. So that means you must have done the `CalcNumSpace` and `calcNumStars` calculations before even though you say you can't do the same calculations in this program. I would guess that you don't properly understand how functions work. For instance you say 'What should I do here to update space every time row increase 1` but that's not right. You don't have to update anything, you have to **calculate** the number of spaces on each row.

Comment: Work out a formula for the number of spaces on a row given the row and the total number of rows. You **must** have had that formula in your first program so all you have to do is copy it here. If you are still stuck then try things, try a few different formulae and see what difference they make to the shape that is produced. Finally if you are really really stuck then write down you best attempt post it here and ask what is wrong with it. People like to see the effort you have made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint for the `calcNumSpace` part.

You need to think of this as simple straigth lines:

[image]

So there are two different lines depending on the input x (aka `row`).

So your code will be:

```
if (x <= X0)
{
     space = -x + Y0
}
else
{
     space =  x - Y0
}
```

So all you need to do now is figure out the value of X0 and Y0. I'll leave that as an exercise for you. Hint: they only depend on `nRows`.

Another hint: Since the lines are symmetric, you can use `abs` instead of the `if` statement. Like

```
 space = -x + Y0
 space = abs(space);
```

For the `calcNumStars` function you can apply the same logic.